# BeautifulSoup4 - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm new to BS4 and I've read through all the similar questions. I'm trying to scrape a number from a sentence so that I can loop through all the pages. The sentence is, "Page 1 of 5" and I'm trying to get the number "5" and store it into a variable. However, I'm facing an error saying that *AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'*. Below is the HTML:

[image]

This is the code I tried.

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
    
    url = 'https://www.edgeprop.my/buy/kelantan/all-residential?page=1'
    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.79 Safari/537.36'}
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    
    total_pages = soup.find('div', class_="tep-page-count").get_text()
    print(total_pages.strip())
```

Some try and error solution I have tried is by replacing the *html.parser* with *lxml*, replacing the class name with *text-center*, *listing-col*, *wavy* and *listing-wrapper* and neither both works.

Comment: Tell me what data do you want  to scrapy, the url is dynamic and total pages option too.

Comment: I'm trying to get the total page number only since I already managed to scrape the data but only for page 1. Since each state has a different total page number, so I'm trying to make a loop by the total page number. EDITED: the data I already scraped is title, location, price, sqft, bedroom, bathroom, agent_name, and agent_phone_no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you see on the page is loaded from external URL via JavaScript (so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it). To get total number of properties found you can use this example:

```py
import json
import requests

url = "https://www.edgeprop.my/jwdsonic/api/v1/property/search?=&listing_type=sale&state=Kelantan&property_type=rl&start=0&size=20"
data = requests.get(url).json()

# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print("Total number of properties found:", data["found"])
```

Prints:

```
Total number of properties found: 84
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this sir. However, do you know how can I get the total page number? I'm assuming we can scrape it by the text under the pagination saying "Page 1 of 5". I already managed to scrape the data I want but only for page 1 with json. Since each state has a different total page number, so I'm trying to make a loop by the total page number.

Comment: @AhmadNasaiei The total number of results are 84. There are 20 results per page - so 84/20=4.2 (so 5 pages total)